# How can I get the Xception config file for coco dataset?

Tags: tensorflow

I am working on an object detection problem. I am having 5000 images per class. I wanted to train the images using Inception V2, Inception V3, and Xception. I got the config files of coco dataset for Inception V2 and InceptionV3 but I cannot find the config file for Xception.

Can anybody help me how to get the Xception config file for Coco dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using TensorFlow's Object Detection API, then you cannot use Xception out of the box. The combinations of backbones with detection architectures that are implemented in the OD API can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/models) and corresponding config files in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs).
You can theoretically implement a combination of your own by taking one similar (e.g. ssd_inception_v2_feature_extractor), and modifying its code to match your needs. However, you still need the backbone to be available in the [slim API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim). Best to my knowledge, Xception is not available there, but you can again try to do it by yourself by adapting [Xception code from deeplab](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/core/xception.py).